# Enum Syntax sugar

Tags: c#, enums

I have a enum, that holds some states. The problem is that enum values name are not ok for the ReSharper. And I am using their values in case operator - all seems fine, but the problem is that case could have only constant values. So, I could not play with string chars adjustment. how to solve this?

```
enum OperationStates
{
 OperationName, //<- this naming is ok for ReSharper
 OperationERROR //<- this is not ok, suggested is OperationError
}
```

but later I have

```
case nameof(OperationStates.OperationERROR):
```

So, I would like to change naming in enum and have something like

```
case nameof(OperationStates.OperationError).ToLower(): //<- but this is not working
```

in my case casting switch value to enum is bad idea - there are too many possible variants, and enum contains only few of them. I am not interesting in catching all available Operations that could arrive, but only this, which correspond to already pre-defined in enum states

Comment: Enums don't have members, they have values. `nameof` don't work on values. Use [Enum.GetName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getname?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: "are not ok for the ReSharper"... This implies that ReSharper is presenting some kind of warning or error. Please tell us the exact warning or error message you are receiving, preferably as text.

Comment: What is the switch statement switching on? Do you have control over that? Can you make it produce the string `OperationError` instead? If not, I'd just silence ReSharper.

Comment: Instead of forcing the enum value to a string, can you parse the switch-value to your enum? (and then switch on the enum value). The parse can be case-insensitive

Comment: ReSharper: "Name OperationERROR does not match rule 'Enum members, suggested name is OperationError'"

Comment: `nameof` does work as expected on an enum value. ToLower also works. However, you cannot have a `case` with an expression, only with a compile-time constant value

Comment: You seem to be confused about the purpose of enums. They associate numbers with a small, fixed number of values, known as tags. They are *not* sets of strings -- if you want that, actually have a set of strings, as a `List` or `HashSet`, for example. You can supply the latter with `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to make it do case-insensitive comparisons. If you want, you can build this set from your enum with `Enum.GetValues`. You could also have a `Dictionary<string, OperationStates>` this way (or indeed the other way around).